# What is the proper name for compositions like (f∘g)(x)

Tags: functions, notation, terminology, function-and-relation-composition

Addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division of functions, $(f+g)(x)$, $(f-g)(x)$, $(f×g)(x)$, $(f÷g)(x)$, are fairly common. Is there an established name for such operations on functions using any operator to compose $f$ and $g$, similar to how $(f∘g)(x)$ is called *function composition*?

In other words, how do we call $(f*h)(x)$ where $*$ denotes a binary operation?

The mathematician [Kenneth E. Iverson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_E._Iverson) called this a [*fork*](https://aplcart.info/?q=(f%20g%20h)%20function#) (full [APL documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Introduction/Trains.htm)), but this terminology clearly wasn't accepted (unlike [other mathematical terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation) he invented), because *fork* doesn't find me anything on Wikipedia or MathWorld.

Comment: I believe that "sum, difference, product and ratio of functions" is quite clear when this has a meaning (for example, for real functions).

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia calls this action *lifting an operation pointwise*, thereby forming a *pointwise operation*.

From the Wikipedia article "[Pointwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pointwise&oldid=885501177#Formal_definition)":

> A binary operation $o: Y × Y → Y$ on a set $Y$ can be lifted pointwise to an operation $O: (X→Y) × (X→Y) → (X→Y)$ on the set $X→Y$ of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ as follows: Given two functions $f_1: X → Y$ and $f_2: X → Y$, define the function $O(f_1,f_2): X → Y$ by
>
> $$(O(f_1,f_2))(x) = o(f_1(x),f_2(x)) \text{ for all } x∈X.$$
>
> Commonly, $o$ and $O$ are denoted by the same symbol. A similar definition is used for unary operations $o$, and for operations of other arity.

Comment: So you'd say $(f+g)(x)$ is the pointwise addition of $f$ and $g$ and for an arbitrary function $h(x_1,x_2)$ it'd be the pointwise $h$ of $f$ and $g$. Nice.

Comment: That is a good point, but as you stated only works when you start with a binary operation on $Y$, right? I am not sure whether that is what the op wanted as he said "using any operator to compose $f$ and $g$". Guess we will have to wait for him to reply. @Adám Yes, that is what one calls the multiplications of functions that are defined as $(f * g)(x) = f(x) * g(x)$ i.e. that are given by using  a binary operation defined on the codomain.

Comment: @ThorWittich Yes, obviously, the combining operation must be binary. $(O(f,g))(x)$ works as a notation, but I do find infix much easier: $(f*g)(x)$ where $x_1*x_2=h(x_1,x_2)$ e.g. $(f*g)(x)$ where $x_1*x_2=\sqrt[x_1]{x_2}$ though I guess one could write $(\sqrt[f]g)(x)$…

Comment: That was not the question. The question was whether you wanted to start with a binary operation on sets or on functions. The former can always be lifted to the latter and are called pointwise ... then. But from your question it is not clear whether you only want to consider examples that arise pointwise or not.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it has its own name (at least one that is widely accepted). I would just "multiply" the functions and specify which "multiplication" is being used. That is mostly based on the fact that one often uses the word "multiplication" for the binary operation of a semigroup/monoid/group etc. So I guess that is just the way to go.

Comment: Ah, similar to how we use *outer product* even if the actual operation isn't multiplication.

Comment: Basically, yes. Even addition is some multiplication in that sense. Multiplication is also some multiplication as stupid as it sounds.